# Is there a C equivalent of Java Waits and Notify?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm using posix threads and have a workerRoutine that in some cases has to wait for I/O.

```
//WorkerRoutine
while(true){
    if(NO CURRENT WORK){
      //sleep for I/O
      continue;
    }
    //Other cases....
}
```

My I/O function updates a statically-sized list. My problem is, when there's no current work for a worker, there's busy waiting. I'd like to have a sleep function in the worker function and a wake function in my readList (the I/O) function. What's the best way to do this in C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest pthreads equivalent of Java's `wait` and `notify` methods are available as functions accepting *condition variables*. Set up a condition variable, call [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) to wait for work, and [`pthread_cond_signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) to announce that work is available.

Usage examples can be easily found [on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772586/1600898) and [elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/rtv/4989304).

If you are waiting for IO, another possibility is to use [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) or equivalent to sleep until data arrives.

Comment: Yes, this is very closely analogous to Java's `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`, including the relationship with a mutex (Java: monitor).  There is also `pthread_cond_broadcast()` as an analog of Java's `Object.notifyAll()`.